# How can I compare having accounts at various banks without opening an account?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, online-banking, savings-account, checking-account

I currently have an HSBC checking, savings, credit card, and overdraft protection account. I do not like HSBC though for a number of reasons, so I'm looking into transferring to a different bank. However, I don't know how I can really compare them without actually opening an account.

In specific, I find the HSBC website and mobile app impossible to use, their security system is unnecessarily complicated (which leads to poor security on my part because I can never remember one of my 3 passswords...), their phone support system also complicated, and they dont many many ATMs in my area.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your best option is to use the internet to look for sites comparing the various features of accounts, and especially forums that are more focused on discussion as you can ask about specific banks and people who have those accounts can answer.

"Requests for specific service provider recommendations" are off-topic here, so I won't go into making any of my own bank recommendations, but there are many blogs and forums out there focusing on personal finance.

Comment: And/or ask your friends what their experiences have been. And/or recognize that none of them are completely awful, and that if you decide you've guessed wrong you can always change banks again. For ATM's, there are several no-fee ATM networks; look for a bank that participates in one of those and you'll be able to use ATMs at many other banks just as easily. (My credit union is 200 miles away, but I have no shortage of ATMs available.)